# Firebase REST-API to create shorted dynamic-links with iOS minimum version

Tags: firebase, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm using Firebase to generate dynamic links backend side.

I need to generate shorted links, so I'm using this approach as suggested into the documentation:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/dynamic-links/link-shortener

I noticed that, into this documentation, there isn't a parameter to specify the minimum version of the iOS app (similar like '`androidMinPackageVersionCode`').

This is strange because using the manual approach this seams possible: https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-manually

> imv: The version number of the minimum version of your app that can
> open the link. This flag is passed to your app when it is opened, and
> your app must decide what to do with it.

Wrong documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known feature request. The only workaround for this is to add `imv` in the long link [manually](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-manually) and creating a short Firebase Dynamic Link [using a long link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/rest#create_a_short_link_from_a_long_link).